# ANTLR handling mismatched Input Exception

Tags: java, antlr

I have a grammar which throws a mismatched input exception, as expected when passing a wrong input but the problem is it tries to recover causing Java.lang.outofmemoryexception and thus terminating the thread which I would not like to happen.

How do I handle that? Which function should I override so that it doesn't tries to recover, instead notifies and continues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override either the parser's, or lexer's, `reportError(...)` method, and throw an exception instead of letting ANTLR (trying to) recover.

Also see: [ANTLR 3.0 Error Reporting and Recovery](http://www.antlr.org/blog/antlr3/error.handling.tml).